# only child when more than one parent has that only-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

first time posting, current student learning CSS pseudo-selectors.

Q: if an element is an only-child to two or more different parents, how do you use only-child with respect to only one of the parents?

Context:  I am on CSS Diner on the only-child lesson.  The layout is as follows: apple on a plate, pickle on a plate, pickle on a bento, large orange and small orange on a plate, and pickle on the table itself.  I am supposed to use only-child to select the apple on the plate and the pickle on the plate.  The plates in this scenario are the parent elements.

Obviously the apple on the plate would be apple:only-child.  I'm stuck on the pickle, however, because it is an only child of both a plate and a bento.  My thought would be to simply use plate>pickle, but it sounds from the lesson that I should be able to do this somehow with the only-child selector.

So, is there a way to use only-child to select the pickle on the plate but not on the bento?

Thanks!

Comment: `plate > *:only-child`

Comment: Are they really using plates and tables for examples? What's wrong with using real-world examples, such as a section in an article, a paragraph in a section and a paragraph in an article...

Comment: I think they're just trying to make it fun. I went off their examples because I didn't want to mess up the question by trying to switch to real-world examples when I'm not quite familiar with the selectors.

Comment: andi - thanks! It worked great!

Answer (score 1):

> Q: if an element is an only-child to two or more different parents, how do you use only-child with respect to only one of the parents?

A: you specify which parent you want to match the child with respect to, in conjunction with the child combinator `>`.

In this case, you can safely get away with `plate > :only-child` since only the apple and pickle are the only children of their parent plates; although there is a plate of oranges the oranges aren't the only children, and so they won't match `:only-child`.