# Why do these margins overlap?

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet, why do the `h2` and `p` margins overlap, yet the `p` and `button` margins don't?

I've coloured the backgrounds so you can evidently see that the spacing is off, even though all 3 elements have the same margin....

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#textContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#textContainer>* {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="textContainer" class="col-xs-6">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc con non. Proin ut lacus sodales, rutrum mi vel, faucibus lacus. </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">faucibus lacus</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As stated by [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) (under collapsing margins), *"Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children)."* The `button` element is inline-block by default, therefore the margins do not collapse vertically.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Cheers, honestly I just totally forgot about button being linline.... thanks.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: You might as well post that as an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock - Done.. only because you insisted :)

Comment: @Josh Crozier: I thought of asking andi [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259688/only-child-when-more-than-one-parent-has-that-only-child) to do the same, but I figured they probably couldn't be bothered to write up a long-form answer. So I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by the box model specification, the margins of `inline-block` elements do not collapse:

> [**8 Box model - 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

A `button` element has a `display` of `inline-block` by default, which means that the margins will not collapse by default.

If you change the `display` of the `button` element to a value such as `block`, then the margins will collapse as you are expecting:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#textContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#textContainer>* {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

button.btn {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="textContainer" class="col-xs-6">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc con non. Proin ut lacus sodales, rutrum mi vel, faucibus lacus. </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">faucibus lacus</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

because `h2,p` block elements and `button` - inline-block element. For inline-block elements margins does not overlap

Comment: only if you add `display: block` for `button`